# How to disable analytics for particular API in wso2am

Tags: statistics, wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager

We are working in WSO2-API Manager and WSO2-Analytics server. We are trying to hide/disable analytics configuration for some particular APIs. We are not looking for role-based restriction rather we want to hide/disable entire analytics for that particular APIs.

we don`t want to see analytics update in the wso2 API publisher for some particular APIs.

Comment: Can you specify the API Manager version?

Comment: API Manager Version is 2.5.0.Let me know you feedback

Answer (score 3):

Current implementation does not support such feature to disable analytics for certain API.